# Using constructor and a public function in a class

Tags: php

I tried to create a basic class with a function. Once an instance of the class is created `new BaseClass("hello")` then the constructor function saves the parameter to a variable.
The `->ret_text()` should return with this variable, but it doesn't works. The error is: `unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`

```
class BaseClass {
    var $txt;

    function __construct($text) {
        $txt = $text;
    }

    public function ret_text() {
        return $txt;
    }
}

echo (new BaseClass("hello"))->ret_text();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should access your class variables with `$this->variableName` where `$this` refers to the class you are in.

In your example `$txt` is not the class variable `$txt` but only a variable for the current function (`__construct()`, `ret_text()` or something else). Also you can't call a method directly after the initialization of the class, i.e. `(new Class())->methodName();` will not work for `PHP version < 5.4`. However, it will work for `PHP version => 5.4`.

Instead try this:

```
class BaseClass {
    var $txt;

    function __construct($text) {
        $txt = 'This is a variable only for this method and it\'s not $this->txt.';
        $this->txt = $text;
    }

    public function ret_text() {
        $txt = 'This is a variable only for this method and it\'s not $this->txt.';
        return $this->txt;
    }
}

$bc = new BaseClass("hello");
echo $bc->ret_text();
```